I am facing error : Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, in wordpress
I am facing the error in wordpress while using hello elementor theme
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "display_initial_avatar" not found or invalid function name in /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:326 Stack trace: #0 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<img alt='' src...', Array) #1 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php(3012): apply_filters('get_avatar', '<img alt='' src...', 38, 64, 'leira_letter_av...', '', Array) #2 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/admin-bar.php(329): get_avatar(38, 64) #3 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu(Object(WP_Admin_Bar)) #4 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(349): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #5 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/admin-bar.php(97): do_action_ref_array('admin_bar_menu', Array) #7 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_admin_bar_render('') #8 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(349): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #9 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #10 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/general-template.php(3097): do_action('wp_body_open') #11 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/header.php(28): wp_body_open() #12 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/template.php(810): require_once('/home/aichie5/a...') #13 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/template.php(745): load_template('/home/aichie5/a...', true, Array) #14 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array) #15 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/index.php(15): get_header() #16 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home/aichie5/a...') #17 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/aichie5/a...') #18 /home/aichie5/aichief.com/index.php(18): require('/home/aichie5/a...') #19 {main} thrown in /home/aichie5/aichief.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 326
May be some updating have caused this issue to theme or elementor plugin, can anybody have the idea?
I tried editing class-wp-hook on line 326 $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
but the issue still persists.

Welcome! This doesn't answer your question, but NEVER edit core files. Any changes you make will be overwritten by updates, and it's almost 99.9 percent that the error isn't in the core file, but rather an issue with the plugin/theme that needs to be addressed by the developer of the plugin/theme.

It looks like the function display_initial_avatar is not found or is not a valid callback. display_initial_avatar function is likely being referenced in a hook or filter, but it doesn't exist or hasn't been defined.
Also you can add fallback function to handle fatal error.
function display_initial_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
    // Here you can add your custom avatar logic.
    return $avatar;
}

